# How to move a single text label in a plot w/o changing x-y-coordinates?

Tags: r, plot, label, rworldmap

I want to add country labels (actually ten) to a `rworldmap`. Two of them overlap because they're small, bordering states. I want to move one of them a little to the side, but keep the first one in place.

I think I don't need to show the `rworldmap` code here since I could break down the issue to the `text` function.

From the function's arguments defaults

```
text(x, y = NULL, labels = seq_along(x$x), adj = NULL,
     pos = NULL, offset = 0.5, vfont = NULL,
     cex = 1, col = NULL, font = NULL, ...)
```

I would conclude that the default `pos` is `NULL`, so I say `pos=c(NULL, 4)`. However this doesn't work as expected; the first label is also moved. The `moveString` is moved correctly, but the other should stay where it is. I have tried all available `pos` for the `stayString`, but they do not correspond to the original position. I also tried `adj` with no success.

```
plot(0:3, type="n")
grid()
text(c(2, 2.2), rep(3, 2), c("stayString", "moveString"), 
     col="black")  # raw
text(c(2, 2.2), rep(2.5, 2), c("stayString", "moveString"),
     pos=c(NULL, 4), col="red")  # unexpected result

# other attempts
text(c(2, 2.2), rep(2, 2), c("stayString", "moveString"),
     pos=c(1, 4), col="green")
text(c(2, 2.2), rep(1.5, 2), c("stayString", "moveString"),
     adj=c(.5, 1), col="blue")
text(c(2, 2.2), rep(1, 2), c("stayString", "moveString"),
     pos=c(2, 4), col="purple")
text(c(2, 2.2), rep(.5, 2), c("stayString", "moveString"),
     pos=c(1, 4), adj=c(.5, 1), col="orange")
```

[image]

I am rather looking for such an adjustment solution because I don't like to change the coordinates since they nicely represent the center of each country.

How can I move the `moveString` and keep the `stayString` in position without changing the `x`/`y` coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that comes to mind is to create two functions, and split each string based on the fact that you want to `offset` it or not.

We can use, from `text()`, `pos` and `offset` to move the text a little.

```
text_stay <- function(x, y, lab, ...) {
  text(x,y, labels=lab, ...)
}

text_move <- function(x,y,lab, p=4, off=2, ...) {
  text(x, y, labels=lab, pos=p, offset=off, ...)
}
```

So for example:

```
plot(0:3, type="n")
grid()
# split the text and use the appropriate wrapper function
text_stay(rep(2, 3), 1:3, "stay", col="red")
text_move(rep(2, 3), 1:3, "move", col = "blue")
```

[image]